# Problems after install

Tags: system-installation

After WIndows installer successful, and booting, systems seems to bog down to almost non-responsive when desktop menu items are selected.  Is there a minimum ram or other system req?

Answer (score 0):

**[System Requirements](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements)**

700 MHz processor (about Intel Celeron or better)

512 MiB RAM (system memory)

5 GB of hard-drive space (or USB stick, memory card or external drive but see LiveCD for an alternative approach)

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Ubuntu 2D? Before you log in, but after you select your user name, click the gear icon and select Ubuntu 2D. Try logging in and see if you still have a problem. Also, try to install drivers for your graphics card(Even if it is just a chipset). If you have an ATI card, use `sudo apt-get install flgrx` from the terminal, and if you have an Nvidia card, use `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current`, also from the terminal. If you need help with that, just comment.(New users can comment anywhere on their question)